# How to use "rel" attribute with image map

Tags: jquery, html, css, popupwindow, imagemap

I have a jquery popup which fires different popups (DIVs) on clicking different links. It is working fine. But now I want it for image map. But it seems that "rel" attribute is not working for image map.
See the Fiddle - http://fiddle.jshell.net/B6A38/

Though W3schools says that it is fine to use "rel" with image map - http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_area_rel.asp

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

The `rel` attribute can be used only if your document type is `HTML5`, i.e. your page *must*
start with

`<!doctype html>` line.

For anchors containing the `href` attribute, this attribute specifies the relationship of the target object to the link object. The value is a comma-separated list of relationship values.

The values and their semantics will be registered by some authority that might have meaning to the document author. The default relationship, if no other is given, is `void`. Use this attribute **only if the `href` attribute is present**.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area) for details.

Also, a side-note, do not trust the [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) web site, it has nothing to do with the [w3c consortium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web_Consortium).

Comment: I know about <!doctype html> and HTML5 and I am using it in my page as well. Can anyone have a solution of the issue?

Comment: Use this attribute only if the `href` attribute is present in your `area` tag, or just put empty `href` if you do not need them.

Comment: @bodi0, Yeah, I know this. Please see my Fiddle. I just want a solution of my issue. Any workaround would be much appreciated